# How can I specify a null as an XML attribute for Android?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android.I m trying to run some of the examples in eclipse.I was able to do the simple ones but not database involved applications because they involve 2 .java files(databasemanager class and activity class).
I dont know which to copy where and run.I know it is silly...but consider me being a beginner .Anyone please help me out in this....

here is the link to the database app i tried:
http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/8/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
android:background="@null"
```